# Multilevel SOQL Query (Parent to Children) more than 1 level

Tags: apex, soql, relationships

I am trying to get some related contact information from a SOQL query but have run into the error "SOQL statements cannot query aggregate relationships more than 1 level away from the root entity object."

Here is my relationships;
Activity_List__c <-- Activity_List_Contacts__c --> Contact   (Junction Object)

Activities can have Sub Activities (Only one Level)
Multiple contacts can be assigned to each activity.

Here is my SOQL query :

```
select id, Name,
(select id, Name, 
    (SELECT Id, Contact_Name__r.FirstName,  Contact_Name__r.LastName FROM Activity_List_Contacts__r)
from Activity_Lists__r limit 50000),
(SELECT Id, Contact_Name__r.FirstName,  Contact_Name__r.LastName FROM Activity_List_Contacts__r) 
from Activity_List__c where Campaign__c ='701M0000000O7Ic' limit 50000
```

I know I need to use a map from reading the boards but am not sure how / what I need to do to accomplish it.

Thanks
Colsie

Comment: What is `{1}`? Some sort of merge typo?

Comment: Take a gander at the documentation for [Relationship Queries](https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/dbcom_soql_sosl/Content/sforce_api_calls_soql_relationships.htm). You can only query one level deep.

Comment: {1] is a field list that I use regularly.

Comment: As of API version 58.0, up to five levels of parent-to-child relationship can be queried via REST and SOAP, but not from Apex. https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.soql_sosl.meta/soql_sosl/sforce_api_calls_soql_relationships_query_limits.htm#OneLevelPerQuery

Answer (score 1):

You are right.Subquery can go only one level deep. If I understand your object model correctly, you can get everything using two subqueries in one query like below,

```
SELECT Id, Name,
    (SELECT Contact_Name__r.FirstName, Contact_Name__r.LastName
        FROM Activity_Lists__r LIMIT 50000),
    (SELECT Id, Contact_Name__r.FirstName, Contact_Name__r.LastName
        FROM Activity_List_Contacts__r)
    FROM Activity_List__c
    WHERE Campaign__c IN :subCampaignIds
    OR Campaign__c = :CampaignId
    LIMIT 50000
```

First subquery will return child activity lists, second subquery will return Activity List contacts records from child relationship.

Comment: Thanks Victor - I've just checked the initial SOQL Query and it seems there was a slight issue....   I've edited the SOQL query at the top.

Answer (score -1):

Just following up on this... so as discussed it's not possible to drill down to the 3rd level of children with a single SOQL query.  My solution was to create a separate SOQL query and put these into map.